# Firebase iOS notifications not received on device

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have two kind of firebase notifications, one with the `notification` field and one without (this field it's used by the system to display the banner).

The one **with** is always received, the one **without** is received for a certain row of attempts and then stops being received.

These are the payloads:

The one always being received:

```
{
  "content_available": true,
  "data": {
    "pushCategory": "ALEXA",
    "body": "body",
    "message": "message",
    "title": "status/update",
    "updateStatus": {
      "operationId": "7fc0e1ff-cc0d-4045-8b30-69710bf80c24",
      "status": 0,
      "action": "makecoffee",
      "description": "",
      "stock": {
        "remaining": "91",
        "threshold": "10",
        "depletion": false
      }
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "title": "title",
    "body": "body msg"
  },
  "apns": {
       "headers": {
         "apns-priority": "10"
       }
    },
  "to": "----"
}
```

The one not being received randomly:

```
{
  "content_available": true,
  "data": {
    "pushCategory": "ALEXA",
    "body": "body",
    "message": "message",
    "title": "status/update",
    "updateStatus": {
      "operationId": "7fc0e1ff-cc0d-4045-8b30-69710bf80c24",
      "status": 0,
      "action": "makecoffee",
      "description": "",
      "stock": {
        "remaining": "91",
        "threshold": "10",
        "depletion": false
      }
    }
  },
  "apns": {
       "headers": {
         "apns-priority": "10"
       }
    },
  "to": "----"
}
```

The equivalent notification using directly the APNS servers and without the `alert` field is always received. (the `alert` field is the one that tells the system to display the banner)

I contacted the Firebase support but the issue in ongoing, do you know what could be the issue?

Comment: Is the first one a notification that user sees? The second one a silent notification? I mean why is `content_available` true for both of them?

Comment: If the 2nd one is a silent notification then tl;dr silent notifications chances of delivery is far less than a non-silent notification

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Firebase.
I'm not sure if `apns-priority` in your payload has an effect. I just don't know:

```
  "apns": {
       "headers": {
         "apns-priority": "10"
       }
    },
```

I think you have to get rid of it and just use `priority` field itself. Let Firebase map the fields itself...

From [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref), look for the description of the `priority` parameter and how it behaves differently for `data` vs `notification` :

> Sets the priority of the message. Valid values are "normal" and
> "high." On iOS, these correspond to APNs priorities 5 and 10.
>
> By default, notification messages are sent with high priority, and
> data messages are sent with normal priority. Normal priority optimizes
> the client app's battery consumption and should be used unless
> immediate delivery is required. **For messages with normal priority, the
> app may receive the message with unspecified delay.**
>
> When a message is sent with high priority, it is sent immediately, and
> the app can display a notification.

The payload with `data` ends up ultimately with a *firebase* priority of "normal" which translates to `apns-priority` 5

For `notification` the *firebase* priority of "high" translates to `apns-priority` of 10

For more on apns-priority, see [apns-docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns/)

> The priority of the notification. If you omit this header, APNs sets
> the notification priority to 10.
>
> Specify 10 to send the notification immediately.
>
> Specify 5 to send the notification based on power considerations on
> the user’s device.

Comment: HI, thanks for the answer, even if I change the payload using: `"priority": "high"` and deleted the apns field the result remains the same.